# Does python run all computations in double percision?

Tags: python, numpy

I know MatLab does everything in double, I heard about the similar thing for python but not quite sure. Can anyone confirm it with reference? Thanks!

Comment: MATLAB does things in double by default, but you can specify single or one of various integer precisions if you want.

Comment: so the only difference will be the size of the variables?

Comment: Between single and double precision floats, yes.  However, there are signed and unsigned integers.  Unsigned integers cannot be negative, but have a higher maximum possible value than their signed counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's a simplification.

- The `float` type in Python is double-precision.
- The `int` type has integer precision, but only limited by memory.  Large numbers can have far more significant digits than a double float.
- When using NumPy, you may choose the precision you want.

Comment: Can I assume SciPy can also do single precision computation like NumPy?

Comment: @GTWu: SciPy is basically just some more stuff on top of NumPy, it doesn't change much in terms of the way things work.